# svn merge conflict for identical files with common ancestor

Tags: svn, merge

When merging back to trunk from a long lived branch, I am getting hundreds of conflicts like the following one.

```
Conflict discovered when trying to add 'src/main/python/application/mail.py'.
An object of the same name already exists.
Select: (mf) my version, (tf) their version, (p) postpone,
        (q) quit resolution, (h) help: tf
svn: warning: W155027: Tree conflict can only be resolved to 'working' state; '/home/me/dev/trunk/src/main/python/application/mail.py' not resolved
svn: E205011: Failure occurred resolving one or more conflicts
```

However these files are identical (svn diff returns no output) and share a common ancestor.

```
svn mergeinfo ^/branches/2_3_RELEASE/src/main/python/application/mail.py ^/trunk/src/main/python/application/mail.py
    youngest common ancestor
    |         last full merge
    |         |        tip of branch
    |         |        |         repository path

    20821              20831
    |                  |
       --| |------------         branches/2_3_RELEASE/src/main/python/application/mail.py
      /
     /
  -------| |------------         trunk/src/main/python/application/mail.py
                       |
                       20831
```

We are a large project with multiple releases in flight at the same time. 2.2 was cut from trunk, 2.3 created from 2.2 and then 2.2 merged back to trunk and 2.3 rebased from trunk.

```
Trunk
|
|\ create 2.2
| *
| *
| |\ create 2.3
| * |
| |  \
| |\ /
| | * merge 2.2 to 2.3
|/  *
*   |  2.2 released and merge to trunk
|\ /
| *  rebase 2.3 from trunk
| *
|/
*   merge 2.3 to trunk, what I'm attempting now
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Think about migration to Mercurial with such branching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in workflow, it's just heightened expectations and one of the well-known and still unavoidable weaknesses of SVN